# Is it posible to change the scope of your Facebook Connect website?

Tags: facebook

I'm building a Facebook app with Facebook login via Oauth 2.0. Will it be possible to request more permissions (scope) from the user in the future as we add features or do we need to request them all up front?

Anyone implemented this with Facebook Connect?

Comment: Just want to add that not only is this possible, it is a best practice.  Only prompt for the permissions you need when you need them.  If you prompt for lots of permissions on app install, before a user even knows what your app really does, you will see a lot of users just bounce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, you can add permissions later and it'll prompt the user to accept those permissions. For my app, I started with just basic/email permissions and then added photo... and it would prompt for the photo.

Comment: Yes I can confirm, if you're set up correctly, this is how things work!

Answer (score 1):

You can call Facebook's permissions api (https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=...) to see if the user has authorized the permission you will need (perhaps they later when in and revoked part of your apps permission but not all of it).  If they did, or you just later need different permissions, just show the authorization link like you did the first time with the additional permissions listed in the url (&scope=email,read_stream...) and it will prompt them for those.