# How I can one more scopes to omniauth account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I want split scopes in two options:
1. for offline_access,email,user_relationships
2. for offline_access,email,user_relationships and xmpp_login

How I can add both scopes and switch between them?

Comment: I don't know what provider you are using but maybe this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292418/is-it-posible-to-change-the-scope-of-your-facebook-connect-website . Also, couldn't you create two apps, each with a different key, secret and scope? But I'm not sure if that is an acceptable solution.

Comment: i'm already solved the problem but forget about this question on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it with

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Setting.for(:facebook_id), Setting.for(:facebook_secret), scope: 'offline_access,email,user_relationships'
config.omniauth :facebook_extended, Setting.for(:facebook_id), Setting.for(:facebook_secret), scope: 'offline_access,email,user_relationships,xmpp_login', name: :facebook_extended, strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
```